# Autocomplete displaying nothing jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have this piece of code.

```
    $("#id_bezeichnung").autocomplete({
        source: "{% url 'getTumorstadiumtyp' %}",
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#id_bezeichnung" ).val( ui.item.bezeichnung);
            return false;
        }
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>"+ item.bezeichnung + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

I've got an json response like this

```
     [{"bezeichnung": "Harnblase"}, {"bezeichnung": "Harnblasentumor"}]
```

The list under the input fields contains the values but they aren't displaying.

Where's the problem?

Comment: post your full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Just try using something like this:

```
$("#id_bezeichnung").autocomplete("getTumorstadiumtyp", {
    dataType: "json",
    ...
});
```

Also check this out: http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-json-example.html